# Query Cloud SQL Database from Python

Tags: python, mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I want to insert data into a [CloudSQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/) MySQL database from a local Python application, is this possible, if so how?

I have tried running the examples at the bottom of https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/#Python_complete_python_example

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(unix_socket='/cloudsql/PROJECT-ID:INSTANCE-NAME', user='phil')

cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('SHOW VARIABLES')
for r in cursor.fetchall():
  webapp2.RequestHandler.response.write('%s\n' % str(r))

db.close()
```

However I get the error:

```
`Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's possible, but that's the documentation for using it specifically from App Engine. Rather, you should use the docs for [connecting from an external application](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/external) - you'll need to configure access, then set mysqldb to connect via IP rather than a local socket.